# Call all objects from database with firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I got a questions. Is it possible to retrieve all objects from a specific node through a cloud function in Firebase? A HTTP Trigger. Like when you call the function it will retrieve all objects. Just like a "GET All" function.

My second question is. I know there is an onWrite function but is there also an onRead function?

I couldn't find the answers on the firebase documentation or I didn't searched good.

Comment: you want to use REST? Have you tried
`GET https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio-demo.com/`

Comment: With Cloud Functions for Firebase you can [access the Firebase database through its Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start). See for an example of this: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/user-data-cleanup

Comment: what do you mean onRead? everytime someone access it, you want it fired?

Comment: It was a example but what I'm trying to do is create a getter for all objects and save that in a var. Afterwards I want to filter out the older dates, but I don't want them removed from the database. I'm trying to do that in a HTTP trigger in cloud functions of firebase.

Comment: is the ultimate goal to get all objects where the date is newer than some parameter?

Comment: Yes, something like that! I could do this in the app, but I was wondering if it is possible to do this through the cloud function. It's something less for the app to handle.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase ADMIN database reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Database#ref)

> `ref(path)` Optional path representing the location the returned Reference will point. *If not provided, the returned Reference will point to the root of the Database.*

Comment: I want to create a HTTP Trigger (GET call). I looked through the link you gave. It gave me some good look, but when I try this code it will output the following:

TypeError: admin.database.ref is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous>


`exports.getAllNotifies = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => { 
 //eventually i want here some logic for filter some objects out.

 return admin.database().ref('/users');
});`

Comment: did you import `admin`? 

    `const admin = require('firebase-admin');`

Comment: I did `const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);`